# Cairo-Dock: is it possible to ungroup windows?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, gnome, taskbar, mate

Very simple question: how to I ungroup similar windows in Cairo-Dock? I wanted to have my Pidgin contacts list separate from my chat window, so I can open each of them through one interaction only - and other cases, such as separate Chrome windows and such.

> *I used to be a fan of AWN, but the project is abandoned... So, after a while using pure Gnome/MATE panels, I've shifted back to a dock to save space in my screen. I really miss the ability to see the different windows I have, and only have them grouped if there's really no space for so many windows.*

Answer (score 2):

Doing a hard search I've found that (this is going to be useful to be found on Google, there were no results):

1. Open Cairo-Dock settings
2. Switch to `Advanced mode` (button at the bottom)
3. Open `Behaviour` category
4. Open `Taskbar` settings
5. Untick "Group windows from the same application in a sub-dock ?"

You can also search for "group" and open the `Taskbar` result.